# How to automatically drop the dropdown menu if my cursor pointed to the navlinks

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have question regarding on customizing the dropdown menu of bootstrap 4, I have module where I need to show the content of dropdown menu If the user hover the different navlinks. Is there way to show the content on the dropdown. If I hover it.? I found some answer related on my question but it's not working on my side they give suggestion use css or jquery.

I will share to you guys my html bootstrap navbar.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-dark" style="height: 56px; background-color:#575A5D !important; border-color:#575A5D !important; position:fixed; width: 100%; z-index:3;">
<button class="custom-toggler navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"  style="color:white !important;" data-target=".navbar1and2" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon" style="color:white !important;"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar1and2" id="navbarSupportedContent2">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" >
<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
MEMBERSHIP
</a>   
<div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
<p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">Benefits For</p>
<div style="border-right-style: dotted;  height:auto; "></div>
<a href="./physician_membership.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; border-color:#00A0DF; background-color:#00A0DF; font-size:16.5px !important; "><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Physician</a>
<br><br>
<a href="./residents.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; border-color:#00A0DF; background-color:#00A0DF; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Residents & Fellows-in-Training</a>
<br><br>
<a href="./medical_students.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-radius: 50px; text-align: left;border-radius:  border-color:#00A0DF; background-color:#00A0DF; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medical Students</a>
<br><br>
<a href="./international_membership.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C; border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> International</a>
<br><br>
<a href="./affiliate_membership.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Affiliate</a>

</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
<p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">Become a Fellow</p>
<ul style="list-style-type: circle; ">
<li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Interested in becoming fellow?</a></li><br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Nominate a fellow <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:10px;">
<p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">For Members</p>
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
<li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="far fa-gem"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Pay Dues <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-th-list"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Update Account <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-money-check"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp; Check Orders <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
CME & MOC
</a>

<div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

<p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">UNDERSTANDING MOC</p>
<p>PSMID offers a number of resources to help members make sense of the MOC requirements and earn points.</p>


<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-color:#007BFF; background-color:#007BFF; border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Understand MOC Requirements</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#007BFF; background-color:#007BFF;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Earn MOC Points</a>

</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
<p style="font-size:30px; color:#000">Industry Leading Tools & Resources</p>
<ul style="list-style-type: none; ">
<li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"> MKSAP 18</a></li><br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><img src="./Assets/annals_icon.png" class="img-fluid"> &nbsp;&nbsp;  Annals of IM </a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><img src="./Assets/im2020-57x57.png" class="img-fluid"> &nbsp;&nbsp;  Internal Medicine Meeting </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">

<div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
<p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">CME</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">MOC</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Certification Preperation</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Online Learning Center</a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
MEETING & COURCES
</a>

<div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><img src="./Assets/im2020-logo-350x115.png" class="img-fluid">
<br><br>  
<p style="font-size:18px; color:#8e908f;">The most comprehensive meeting in Internal Medicine.</p>
<hr>

<p style="font-size:27px; color:#8e908f;">Los Angeles,CA April 23-25, 2020</p>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:15px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> INTERNAL MEDICINE MEETING 2020</a>

</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
<p style="font-size:30px; color:#000">Upcoming Internal Medicine Board Review Courses</p>
<p style="font-size:20px; color:#8e908f">Prepare for the Certification and Maintenance of Certification (MOC) Exam with an PSMID review course.</p>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:15px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> BOARD CERTIFICATION REVIEW COURCES</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:15px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> MOC EXAM PREP COURCES</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">

<div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
<p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Internal Medicine Meeting</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">US Chapter Meetings</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">International Chapter Meetings</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Courses & Recordings</a>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Focused Topics</a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</li>

<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
CLINICAL INFORMATION
</a>

<div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-8" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

<center>
<br>
<div style="line-height: 5px;">

<p style="font-size:30px;">PSMID Clinical Search</p>
<h5 style="font-size:20px;">Treating a patient? Researching a topic? Get answers now.</h5>



<div class="input-group  col-md-7">

<input type="text" class="form-control" style="position: relative; top:7px; font-size: 15px; "  placeholder="Search Clinical Information" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
<div class="input-group-prepend" style="position: relative; top:7px;  ">
<span class="input-group-text"  id="basic-addon1" style="background-color: #00A0DF !important; border-color:#00A0DF; color:white; "><i class="fas fa-search" style="font-size:15px;"></i></span>
</div>

</div>
<br><br>
<hr>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="./Assets/logo-annals3.png" class="img-fluid">
<br><br><br><br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> VISIT ANNALS</a>
<br><br><br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:15px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">LEARN MORE</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="./Assets/logo-annals3.png" class="img-fluid">
<br><br><br><br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> VISIT MKSAP 18</a>
<br><br><br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:15px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">LEARN MORE</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="./Assets/dmp_logo_v3.png" class="img-fluid">
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> VISIT DYNAMED PLUS</a>

</div>
</div>
</div>


</div>
</center>


</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">

<div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
<p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Clinical Guidelines & Recommendations</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Performance Measures</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Journals & Publications</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Clinical Resources & Products</a>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">High Value Care</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Ethics & Professionalism</a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</li>

<!--       <li class="nav-item " style="padding-right:60px; color:white;">
<a class="nav-link" href="#" >CLINICAL INFORMATION</a>
</li> -->

<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
PRACTICE RESOURCES
</a>

<div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-3" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

<p style="font-size:25px; color:#8e908f">Medicare</p>
<p style="font-size:18px;">Ensure payment and avoid policy violations. Plus, new resources to help you navigate the Medicare Access and CHIP Reauthorization Act of 2015 (MACRA).</p>

<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medicare Resources</a>

</div>
<div class="col-md-3" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
<p style="font-size:25px; color:#8e908f">Office Forms</p>
<p style="font-size:18px;">Access helpful forms developed by a variety of sources for patient charts, logs, information sheets, office signs, and use by practice administration.</p>

<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Office Forms</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" style=" position: relative; top:10px;">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">QUICK LINKS</p>
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
<li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> QPP/MACRA </a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>Physician & Practice Timeline </a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Coding</a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medical Educator Resources</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
<p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">CME</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">MOC</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Certification Preperation</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Online Learning Center</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</li>

<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
ADVOCACY
</a>

<div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:auto; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-8" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

<br>
<div style="line-height: 5px;">

<p style="font-size:30px;">Where We Stand</p>
<h5 style="font-size:20px;">PSMID advocates on behalf on internists and their patients on a number of timely issues. Learn about where PSMID stands on the following areas:</h5>


</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Access to Care</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Patients Before Paperwork</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medicare and the Quality Payment Program</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medicaid Reform</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Public Health</a>

</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Physician Workforce and Team Based Care</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Women in Medicine</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Health Information Technology</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medical Liability Reform</a>
</div>
</div>
<br>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">

<div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
<p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Where We Stand</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">PSMID Advocate Newsletter</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">State Health Policy</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Advocacy in Action</a>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Current Public Policy Papers</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">PSMID Policies & Recommendations</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item " style="color:white !important;">
<a class="nav-link" href="#" style=""><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> STORE</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#navbarDropdown').hover(function() {
          $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
        }, function() {
          $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution via JQuery**

Rather than doing `.fadeIn / .fadeOut`.

Just use `.toggleClass` and then toggle the class "show" on `.nav-item` and `.dropdown-menu`.

See the code below.

```js
$('.nav-item').hover(
          function() {
            $('.nav-item.show').stop(true, true).delay(200).removeClass("show");
            $('.nav-item').find('.dropdown-menu.show').stop(true, true).delay(200).removeClass("show");

            $(this).stop(true, true).delay(200).toggleClass("show");
            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).toggleClass("show");
        }, function() {
            
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-dark" style="height: 56px; background-color:#575A5D !important; border-color:#575A5D !important; position:fixed; width: 100%; z-index:3;">
<button class="custom-toggler navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"  style="color:white !important;" data-target=".navbar1and2" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon" style="color:white !important;"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar1and2" id="navbarSupportedContent2">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" >
<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
MEMBERSHIP
</a>   
<div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
<p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">Benefits For</p>
<div style="border-right-style: dotted;  height:auto; "></div>
<a href="./physician_membership.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; border-color:#00A0DF; background-color:#00A0DF; font-size:16.5px !important; "><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Physician</a>
<br><br>
<a href="./residents.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; border-color:#00A0DF; background-color:#00A0DF; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Residents & Fellows-in-Training</a>
<br><br>
<a href="./medical_students.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-radius: 50px; text-align: left;border-radius:  border-color:#00A0DF; background-color:#00A0DF; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medical Students</a>
<br><br>
<a href="./international_membership.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C; border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> International</a>
<br><br>
<a href="./affiliate_membership.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Affiliate</a>

</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
<p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">Become a Fellow</p>
<ul style="list-style-type: circle; ">
<li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Interested in becoming fellow?</a></li><br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Nominate a fellow <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:10px;">
<p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">For Members</p>
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
<li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="far fa-gem"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Pay Dues <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-th-list"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Update Account <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-money-check"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp; Check Orders <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
CME & MOC
</a>

<div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

<p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">UNDERSTANDING MOC</p>
<p>PSMID offers a number of resources to help members make sense of the MOC requirements and earn points.</p>


<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style="border-color:#007BFF; background-color:#007BFF; border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Understand MOC Requirements</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#007BFF; background-color:#007BFF;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Earn MOC Points</a>

</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
<p style="font-size:30px; color:#000">Industry Leading Tools & Resources</p>
<ul style="list-style-type: none; ">
<li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"> MKSAP 18</a></li><br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><img src="./Assets/annals_icon.png" class="img-fluid"> &nbsp;&nbsp;  Annals of IM </a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><img src="./Assets/im2020-57x57.png" class="img-fluid"> &nbsp;&nbsp;  Internal Medicine Meeting </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">

<div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
<p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">CME</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">MOC</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Certification Preperation</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Online Learning Center</a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
MEETING & COURCES
</a>

<div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><img src="./Assets/im2020-logo-350x115.png" class="img-fluid">
<br><br>  
<p style="font-size:18px; color:#8e908f;">The most comprehensive meeting in Internal Medicine.</p>
<hr>

<p style="font-size:27px; color:#8e908f;">Los Angeles,CA April 23-25, 2020</p>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:15px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> INTERNAL MEDICINE MEETING 2020</a>

</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
<p style="font-size:30px; color:#000">Upcoming Internal Medicine Board Review Courses</p>
<p style="font-size:20px; color:#8e908f">Prepare for the Certification and Maintenance of Certification (MOC) Exam with an PSMID review course.</p>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:15px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> BOARD CERTIFICATION REVIEW COURCES</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:15px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> MOC EXAM PREP COURCES</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">

<div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
<p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Internal Medicine Meeting</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">US Chapter Meetings</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">International Chapter Meetings</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Courses & Recordings</a>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Focused Topics</a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</li>

<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
CLINICAL INFORMATION
</a>

<div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-8" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

<center>
<br>
<div style="line-height: 5px;">

<p style="font-size:30px;">PSMID Clinical Search</p>
<h5 style="font-size:20px;">Treating a patient? Researching a topic? Get answers now.</h5>



<div class="input-group  col-md-7">

<input type="text" class="form-control" style="position: relative; top:7px; font-size: 15px; "  placeholder="Search Clinical Information" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
<div class="input-group-prepend" style="position: relative; top:7px;  ">
<span class="input-group-text"  id="basic-addon1" style="background-color: #00A0DF !important; border-color:#00A0DF; color:white; "><i class="fas fa-search" style="font-size:15px;"></i></span>
</div>

</div>
<br><br>
<hr>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="./Assets/logo-annals3.png" class="img-fluid">
<br><br><br><br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> VISIT ANNALS</a>
<br><br><br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:15px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">LEARN MORE</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="./Assets/logo-annals3.png" class="img-fluid">
<br><br><br><br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> VISIT MKSAP 18</a>
<br><br><br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:15px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">LEARN MORE</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="./Assets/dmp_logo_v3.png" class="img-fluid">
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> VISIT DYNAMED PLUS</a>

</div>
</div>
</div>


</div>
</center>


</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">

<div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
<p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Clinical Guidelines & Recommendations</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Performance Measures</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Journals & Publications</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Clinical Resources & Products</a>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">High Value Care</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Ethics & Professionalism</a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</li>

<!--       <li class="nav-item " style="padding-right:60px; color:white;">
<a class="nav-link" href="#" >CLINICAL INFORMATION</a>
</li> -->

<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
PRACTICE RESOURCES
</a>

<div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:400px; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-3" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

<p style="font-size:25px; color:#8e908f">Medicare</p>
<p style="font-size:18px;">Ensure payment and avoid policy violations. Plus, new resources to help you navigate the Medicare Access and CHIP Reauthorization Act of 2015 (MACRA).</p>

<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medicare Resources</a>

</div>
<div class="col-md-3" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">
<p style="font-size:25px; color:#8e908f">Office Forms</p>
<p style="font-size:18px;">Access helpful forms developed by a variety of sources for patient charts, logs, information sheets, office signs, and use by practice administration.</p>

<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Office Forms</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" style=" position: relative; top:10px;">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<p style="font-size:17px; color:#8e908f">QUICK LINKS</p>
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
<li><a href=""  style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> QPP/MACRA </a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>Physician & Practice Timeline </a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Coding</a></li>
<br>
<li><a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medical Educator Resources</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
<p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">CME</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">MOC</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Certification Preperation</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Online Learning Center</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</li>

<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"  style="padding-right:50px; color:white;" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
ADVOCACY
</a>

<div class="dropdown-menu fade w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="border-radius: 0px; height:auto; background-color:#f3f3f3; border-color:#f3f3f3;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-8" style="border-right-style: dotted; border-right-color: #8e908f; position: relative; top:10px;">

<br>
<div style="line-height: 5px;">

<p style="font-size:30px;">Where We Stand</p>
<h5 style="font-size:20px;">PSMID advocates on behalf on internists and their patients on a number of timely issues. Learn about where PSMID stands on the following areas:</h5>


</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Access to Care</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Patients Before Paperwork</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medicare and the Quality Payment Program</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medicaid Reform</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Public Health</a>

</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Physician Workforce and Team Based Care</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Women in Medicine</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Health Information Technology</a>
<br><br>
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg form-control" style=" border-color:#4AAE9C; background-color:#4AAE9C;border-radius: 50px; text-align: left; font-size:16.5px !important;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Medical Liability Reform</a>
</div>
</div>
<br>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style=" position: relative; top:0px;">

<div style="background-color:#E9ECEF; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
<p style="font-size:25px;">In this section</p>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Where We Stand</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">PSMID Advocate Newsletter</a> <br><br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">State Health Policy</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Advocacy in Action</a>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">Current Public Policy Papers</a> <br> <br>
<a href="" style="font-size:20px; text-decoration: none; color:#00A0DF;">PSMID Policies & Recommendations</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item " style="color:white !important;">
<a class="nav-link" href="#" style=""><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> STORE</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

---

**via CSS**

Just add the style below the declaration of your `bootstrap.css` so it will override the style of bootstrap.

See the [CodePen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vodZvM) for the live code.

.navbar{
      padding: 0;
      height: unset;
    }

```
.nav-item{
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav-item:hover .dropdown-menu{
  display:block;
  background:red;
  opacity:1;
}
</style>
```

---

I suggest you use the JQuery solution because it will not much affect the style of the bootstrap rather than using CSS solution that will cause modification and overriding the style of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CSS only solution :

```
/* Code to place between the <head> </head> tags of your html document */

<style>
    li.nav-item:hover div.dropdown-menu,
    div.dropdown-menu:hover {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100000;
    }

    /* The next 3 declarations are to overwrite the initially declared
       padding and margin on the classes .navbar, .nav-item, and 
      .dropdown-menu */

    nav.navbar {
        padding: 0 1rem;
    }

    li.nav-item {
        padding: .5rem 0;
    }

    li.nav-item div.dropdown-menu {
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

I change the properties (`display`, `opacity`, `position`, `z-index`) of your dropdown-menu when the user hover the `li` element and the `.dropdown-menu` itself.
To make it work I had to *overwrite* the top/bottom padding from the nav bar setting it to 0, add what i "removed" to the `li` elements instead (to keep the design identical), and *overwrite* the margin from the dropdown menus setting it to 0. 
Hovering a *menu item* will show its *dropdown menu* which in turn will stay visible as long as it is hovered. So we need to go from one to the other without interuption. There can't be any gap between them for this solution to work.
In the [bootstrap.min.css](https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css) the `.navbar` is defined with `padding: .5rem 1rem;`, and I overwrite it by declaring `nav.navbar {padding: 0 1rem;}` in the internal style sheet of your document (*see code above and CodePen link below*).

[Here](https://codepen.io/pi-L/pen/zgpabZ) is a working pen.
Note : Instead of using an *internal style sheet* you can ofcourse add the code in an external style sheet as long as the  `<link rel="stylesheet" ...>` you are using comes after the link for *bootstrap.min.css*.

Comment: ? what did you remove on my top bottom padding? where can i find that?